# Can I set A TFS 2012 BUG to Done automatically upon check in from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, alm

When you in visual studio 2013/tfs2012 check in your work associated with A task you can either 'associate' or 'resolve' the task. Setting it to 'resolve' Will automatically move the task on the sprint backlog and the kanban board to 'Done'. This is Nice because AS A developer you only need to check in using the correct status and status everywhere is okay :-).

This does not Seem to be the case with work items of type 'Bug' - here I Can only choose 'associate' inside vs2013 and then I also need to manually Enter web access and set the bug to 'done'. So I'm kind of doing the same work twice.

Can I without customizing TFS work item types or the proces template get this bug status set to 'resolved' as it works with 'tasks' today - and how?

Comment: This could be done using Alerts (and by creating a soap service which would be consumed by tfs alert system), or with a server-side plugin. Would any of those be viable for you?

Comment: It's a Good idea but i want to avoid any kind of 'not out of the box' tfs2012 functionality. So that Will not work for me in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really not a good idea to set a bug as done on checkin. Has the coder verified that the completed output meets the definition of done? How can they hope to do that before they check in?

A bug, just like a PBI, greys set to done when a Development Team decides as a group that out is complete and that they have met ask quality bars.

In the Scrum template Bugs are product level items that confirm to the DoD. However you would break that bug down into a number of tasks at your sprint planning meeting and they can be resolved. The workflow for a bug is:

1) Bug created by tester as the result of a failing test.

2) Bug accepted into the sprint by the Development Team.

3) Bug broken down into tasks for at least coding and testing work.

4) Coder fixes the bug and resolves their Task. The checkin marks this task as Done.

5) Tester validates the Test Case that proves the bugs existence now passes. They mark their Task as Done.

6) The Development Team meets and assesses the doneness of the Bug against the DoD. If done they mark it as Done.

Comment: Thank you. I Will add this proces into our development cycle for bugs (which is also what I came to realize from the previous answers, you answer just crystalizes this even more that I originally misunderstood the intention of the bug workitem in the alm cycle)

Comment: A Good thing to know. Eventhough the bug States are easily googleable (if that's even a Real word...) I was under the assumption until now that both the agile and SCRUM template behave the same.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible - We use "resolve" with every bug (under the Agile template) because it saves such a lot of time. In pending changes, just associate the bug (type in its work item id, or drag and drop the bug into that area of the pending changes) and then you can either "associate" or "resolve" it. (After which the originator can verify the fix and close it)

I presume you're using a template that doesn't offer this facility - so perhaps diff your template against the standard Agile template and you may find the tweak you need to allow this behaviour. Does the template you are using support the "resolved" state on bugs? Perhaps it is missing?

If it is just that your bug template skips the "resolved" state, then it would be trivial to either rename the equivalent state (perhaps it's just not being picked up by the UI because it's not named correctly or not in the correct group?) or insert a new state using the WIT editor.

Comment: We are using the SCRUM 2.1 template and we actually select the bug workitem under my work and during check in from vs2013 there is only the option to 'associate' to the bug - not resolve. Are you suggesting to compare the workitem templates for a bug in the agile and SCRUM templates to verify if the transition to resolved from visual studio is possible? I would very much Like not to customize Tfs to avoid potential Tfs udgrade problems later.

Comment: Yes, this is my guess - it sounds like Scrum doesn't support the "resolve" state, so the user interface doesn't let you select it. I understand how you feel about keeping your template "pure" (and therefore future compatible) but changes like this to a work item template are usually pretty safe (or at least relatively easy to manually merge if a conflict should occur in a future upgrade). Worth checking if a simple tweak would do the trick. IIRC it's the TFS power tools extension that allow you to easily edit work item types from the server.

Comment: I have noticed that neither PBI's nor BUG's support the ability to be set to 'resolved' during check in in Visual Studio (at least not in SCRUM 2.1 template). Tasks do however support this (they can be either 'associated' or 'resolved'). So what I should have done (in order to not modify the WIT) would have been to create a Task underneath my BUG and that could have then been 'resolved' during check-in. In reality both you and @JustTFS helped to understand the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A bugs flow is different from a task.

- A bug is raised (tester / user / Developer)
- A Bug is fixed (Developer)
- A Bug is Tested (built, Integrated to main build, deployed, Tested by Testers)
- A bug is done (signed off by the originator)

is the general flow of a bug, TFS ALM assumes that the fixing and the testing would be done by 2 different roles.

if you want to change this to mirror the task work flow, you would have to alter the template

Answer (score 0):

We also use the **Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.Checkin** action to transition a bug between Development and QA states.  Developers can Associate or Resolve, and Resolve triggers the state change *attempt*.  HOWEVER, if any fields are required in the transition, such as Root Cause, the transition will fail without any error message.  This is unfortunate.  It would be great if the bug popped open and said "Please enter this field."  If required fields are filled in before the checkin, then the state transition happens as expected.